# Push Notification -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, push-notification

When I send a push notification and my app is open or in the background and I click on the push notification, my application redirects to `PushMessagesVc` `viewController` (*as intended*)

I use the code as below for this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    PushMessagesVc *pvc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PushMessagesVc"];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc
                                                 animated:YES
                                               completion:NULL];
}
```

There is no problem in the code/scenario above but if the application is closed and I click on a push notification, the application does not redirect my `PushMessagesVc` `viewController` in this case & the application stays on the main screen.

For the 2nd scenario, I use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sleep(1);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if(apsInfo) {
        UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        PushMessagesVc* pvc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PushMessagesVc"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But in this case, the `PushMessagesVc` does not appear.

Comment: How can i solve my problem?

Comment: what is the warning or error that you get in the debug console? which `viewController` is the initial `viewController` in your storyboard? actually... take a screenshot of the storyboard and include it in the answer.

Comment: There was no error, if the application is not opened, when push message come and I clicked message application stay in main view controller, because if(apsInfo) block is not working in this situation.

Comment: hm... instead of `[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];` try this `[self.window setRootViewController:pvc]`. (_recompile, run on device... but don't get me wrong, this is not the exact answer to your question, it's just to check the whether `if(apsInfo)` block executes or not_)

Comment: Thank you very much, the correct answer is your answer. It is working now. Thank you again.

Comment: It is correctly working but header not showing for instance back button, I thing it is related with the navigation control, Actually there is navigation control, I don't know what is the problem

Comment: `[self.window setRootViewController:pvc]` is not really the right way to do it because now there is no way to go back to your normal app flow. i just wanted to confirm that the `if(apsInfo)` block is working. **you should take a screenshot of the storyboard and include it in the question**.

Comment: ok, since you only want to present a `viewController`, we can do this via `NSNotificationCenter` (_simple and easy_). What's the name of your `rootViewController` (_i.e your initial `viewController`? must be a `navigationController` but which is the `navigationController`'s `rootViewController`?_).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you only want to present a `viewController` when you get a Push Notification, you may try utilizing `NSNotificationCenter` for your purposes:

### Part 1: Set up a class (*in your case, the `rootViewController`*) to listen/respond to a `NSNotification`

*Suppose, **`MainMenuViewController`** is the `rootViewController` of your `navigationController`.

Set up this class to listen to a `NSNotification`:*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(presentMyViewOnPushNotification)
                                                 name:@"HAS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION"
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)presentMyViewOnPushNotification {
    //The following code is no longer in AppDelegate
    //it should be in the rootViewController class (or wherever you want)

    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    PushMessagesVc *pvc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PushMessagesVc"];

    [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    //either presentViewController (above) or pushViewController (below)
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
}
```

---

### Part 2: Post Notification (*possible from anywhere in your code*)

*In your case, **AppDelegate.m** methods should look like*:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //firstly, don't sleep the thread, it's pointless
    //sleep(1); //remove this line

    if (launchOptions) { //launchOptions is not nil
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        if (apsInfo) { //apsInfo is not nil
            [self performSelector:@selector(postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC) 
                       withObject:nil
                       afterDelay:1];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //this method can be done using the notification as well
    [self postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC];
}

-(void)postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HAS_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
}
```

---

PS: I haven't done this for my projects (*yet*) but it works and is the best way i could think of doing this kinda stuff (*for the moment*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I applied your answer in my code, if the application is opened, when push message arrive PushMessagesVc is showed without header bar. On the other hand, if the application is not working, whe message arrive application is closed outomatically.

Comment: @cdsoft : header bar? you want the `navBar`? hm... we're using your `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` method so instead of presenting, we can push, so... try `[self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];` ||| And as for `if the application is not working, whe message arrive application is closed outomatically`... how can application close automatically if it is not working?

Comment: if I add below line, application is closed 
[self performSelector:@selector(onLoadPushNotification) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

Comment: @cdsoft : oh, it's crashing... the method name `onLoadPushNotification` is incorrect (_my mistake_), it should be `postNotificationToPresentPushMessagesVC`. I'll update the answer

Comment: Really awesome. It solves my problem quickly after long attempt.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5**

To get push notification Dictionary in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** when app is kill and push notification receive and user click on that

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let aps1 = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            print(aps1)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

**Push notification Dictionary will display in alert.**

Answer (score 6):

Swift 2.0
For 'Not Running' State (Local & Remote Notification)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


// Handle notification
if (launchOptions != nil) {

    // For local Notification
    if let localNotificationInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {

        if let something = localNotificationInfo.userInfo!["yourKey"] as? String {

            self.window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourController(yourMember: something))
        }


    } else

    // For remote Notification
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! [NSObject : AnyObject]? {

        if let something = remoteNotification["yourKey"] as? String {
            self.window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourController(yourMember: something))
        }
    }

}


return true
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

I write my notification to var "notification" in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and if "notification" != nil started my push in applicationDidBecomeActive, after that removed him ( = nil)

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var notification: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    registerForPushNotifications()

    //write notification to var
    if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
        self.notification = launchOptions![UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
    }

    return true
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if notification != nil {
    //for launch notification after terminate app
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "startPush"), object: nil)
        notification = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift version:

```
   if let localNotification: UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification { //launchOptions is not nil
        self.application(application, didReceiveLocalNotification: localNotification)
    }
```