# didReceiveRemoteNotification is not being called in background mode until I do not tap on notification in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have searched for hours but somewhere is saying that,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandlerNotification
```

is called, regardless of application is in active state or inactive state. Somewhere it says when application is not active it push notification calls your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and there you can detect notification like this :

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]`
```

In my case, both are working if user tap on notification and everything is fine, but the problem occurs when user does not tap on notification and direct open app from its icon, then neither `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` detect it has notification nor `didReceiveRemoteNotification` get called. I need to save messages in database, received from push notification, but without tapping on notification how to call method?

Comment: try to use of - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application method.. when user directly click on app icon then it called definitly, if didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called then also it called..

Comment: @Max obviously didFinishLaunchingWithOptions getting called but it can not detect whether it received push notification or not

Comment: For that problem you can process notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Answer (score 0):

to get notification data in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` do this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

if(launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if(remoteNotif != nil){

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[remoteNotif objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"] integerValue];

            //do something here to process notification



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same issue. It does not detect notification until I do not tap on notification.

Comment: yes but you can process it on app icon click. As when notification arrives and app is in background then no one action is triggered until you click on notification or app.

Comment: tapping on notification action is triggered , that is fine but when I click on app icon, it does nothing, can not process your code, it does not enter in if

Comment: then check after removing first if condition. It is of launching option.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771312/push-notification-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions