# How can I get array of arrived Remote Notifications in iOS when the application open?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently developing an iOS application that receive push notification from the web server.

I can receive my notification just fine when the application run in the background / foreground, but when the device is receiving notification while my application got terminated (swiped from the multitasking mode or lock the device), the `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` method doesn't get called (but the notification & banner does appear!).

So I'm thinking about getting all the arrived (unread) notification and clear all of them when the user launch the application (at `FinishedLauncing` method) and then I can display some of the message first, because fetching the data from the server do takes some time.

**I do can get one message from the `launchOptions` if the user clicked on one of the notification to open my apps. But is there a way to get them all?**

Comment: see this answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771312/push-notification-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

Comment: I see that answer is about how triggering `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and reading the `launchOptions`. What I'm looking for is to get array of received (unread) Notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to get all the notifications you received.

You can only receive payload of notification on which user tapped or selected from the notification center.

But there is a way, using that you can process your every push notification.
add key `content-available` with value `1` in to your `aps` dictionary.

so it will look like,

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        },
        "badge" : 5
        "content-available" : 1
    }
}
```

If iOS system detects pushNotification with this key having value `1`, 
it will call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` of your appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

`userInfo` is the dictionary containing push notifications. `aps` is the key for push notifications body.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
 NSLog(@"userInfo  %@",userInfo);   

 // you can get the required message as below

 NSString *msg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
 NSLog(@"Push Notification:%@",msg);
}
```