# Handle the click of the view in Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Its possible to handle the event when a user touch the notification view?
I need that this click do the same like an action button, which will send a view from a detail place.
Now when the user touchs the view the app only open the current view.

This is my actual code to handle the action button:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    if identifier == ACTION_ONE_IDENTIFIER {...}
```

I need the same for all the view.

Sorry for my english, edit are welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use observers to handle notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "", name:"", object: nil)
```

Same for Post Observer and remove it after reach to viewcontroller.

Comment: And where can I know that the notification is clicked?

Comment: First you have to use  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("natification_name", object: nil)
Then add that notification in viewdidload of viewcontroller which you want to show after click notification
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "method to call", name:"natification_name", object: nil)

Comment: and what about if the user close the app ? Ok its solved with this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771312/push-notification-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

Thanks